# Patch library functions for testing

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

I am currently writing some tests for an application and I want to test error handling.

For instance , I want to check behavior of the application when shutil.copyfile() throws an exception. Since the src and dst for this function is build up inside the function calling shutil.copyfile(), I cannot trigger a failure from my test.

What I currently do is the following.

```
import shutil as f
def __patch():

    def my_func(*args, **kwargs):
        raise f.SameFileError

    f.copyfile = my_func
```

Now, I would expect that anytime copyfile is called within my application, it would throw a SameFileError error. But this does not happen at the moment. The copyfile function from shutil is still being executed.

On the otherhand, if I do the same for a library that has a function to be patched inside a class, the patching works and my custom function replaces the function from the library. This works for patching extractall() function in the zipfile library because the function to be patched is inside a class.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile, BadZipFile
def __patch():

    def my_func(*args, **kwargs):
        raise BadZipFile

    ZipFile.extractall = my_func
```

Can anyone please tell me how I can get this running for the copyfile() from shutil as well. Unfortunately, I cannot use the mock library here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does your application use ``copyfile`` via its qualified name (``shutil.copyfile``) or do you bind it to a local name (``from shutil import copyfile`` or similar)?

Comment: Its using the qualified name

Comment: Please elaborate.Your answer suggests the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

The import should be done as follows:

```
import shutil as copy
```

instead of

```
from shutil import copyfile
```

and then the function should be called as `copy.copyfile()`

Comment: Why do you bind shutil to a different name?